# Did Latin lack a denominal verb directly from 'patria'?

Tags: verbs

According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/repatriate) and [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/162689) (below), Latin had *repatriare*, but English ['patriate'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patriate) wasn't allegedly coined by [Lester B. Pearson until 1966](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=patriate).

1. This tardive coining suggests a lack of a [denominal verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denominal_verb) directly from *patria*. Am I correct?
2. If so, why? Why wasn't there **patriare*? It feels unnatural, outlandish (pun intended), and incomplete to have 
   *re + patriare* but not **patriare*?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, I think you're correct. There is no Lat. denominal verb *patriare* that is directly formed from *patria*. As for the Engl. late verb *patriate*, it was coined from *repatriate* via a backformation process.
2. Why is there no originally unprefixed denominal verb like **patriare*? Well, probably, for the same reason there is no denominal verb like, for example, **dentare* (cf. *edentare*). That is, the reasons involved are probably **not** linguistic but encyclopaedic (for example, having *patriam* or *dentes* is what is naturally unmarked, so to speak). **Linguistically** speaking, there is no reason why one could not form unprefixed denominal locative verbs like *patriare* and *dentare* with the expected/corresponding meanings "provide X with *patria*" and "provide X with teeth", respectively. Cf. the existing unprefixed locative denominal verbs: *humare* ('to provide/cover X with earth'), *marginare* ('to provide X with a border'), *terminare* ('to provide X with bounds', i.e., 'set bounds'), etc.